# Removing the subtractive cancellation of $(a+x)^n - a^n$ as x approaches zero

Tags: calculus, numerical-methods, numerical-calculus

$$(a+x)^n - a^n = \\
e^{n\ln(a+x)}-e^{n\ln(a)} = \\
?$$

This looks simple but I'm stumped.

I've tried to solve this another way too:

$$ f(a) = a^n \\ \frac{\delta f}{\delta a} = \lim_{x\rightarrow 0}\frac{(a+x)^n-a^n}{x}  \\ \\
(a+x)^n - a^n = \frac{(a+x)^n-a^n}{x}x = \frac{\delta f}{\delta n}x=a^n\ln(a)x:x\rightarrow0\\$$

How do I finish the first one, and is the second one correct?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**Hint:** Apply the binomial theorem:
$$(a+x)^n=a^n+nxa^{n-1}+\cdots+nax^{n-1}+x^n.$$
Your second method is incorrect because if you take $f(x)=x^n$, then $f'(x)=nx^{n-1}$. You are taking $f(x)=a^x$.

Comment: In the second one I took $f(n) = a^n$ with x being the h that is used in the formula, does this make sense?

Comment: That would work if your exponent $n$ were going to zero (since then that would be the definition of the derivative of $a^n$), but you have $x$ going to zero instead.

Comment: I see... what if I use $f(a) = a^n$ instead?

Comment: Then that is correct. You would then have $\lim_{x\to0}\big((a+x)^n-a^n\big)/x=\left(na^{n-1}\right)\lim_{x\to0}x=0$.

Comment: Nice. Could you give another hint for the first method?

Comment: Your first method isn't likely to work, since it's no easier to relate the difference $(a+x)^n-a^n$ to the difference $e^{n\ln(x+a)}-e^{n\ln(a)}$ in an elementary way. Differences of exponentials are hard to work with. The best tool here is binomial expansion since this exactly allows you to cancel all terms independent of $x$.

Comment: @Segmentationfault : If you have a complete enough math library, then you can implement this as `pow(a,n)*expm1(n*log1p(x/a))` where `expm1(x)` implements $e^x-1$ and `log1p(x)` implements $\ln(1+x)$ exactly (in the bounds of the floating point format) for small $x$.

Comment: @LutzLehmann Nice example use of those functions!

Answer (score 1):

$$S_n=(a+x)^n-a^n=\sum_{k=1}^n  \binom{n}{k}  a^{n-k} x^k=a^n\sum_{k=1}^n  \binom{n}{k}\left(\frac{x}{a}\right)^k$$ Truncate where ever you want.

If $x \ll a$, the first approximation would be
$$S_n=n  a^{n-1} x$$ but you can have better with
$$S_n=\frac{2 n x a^n}{2 a-(n-1)x}$$